# a working example of web3modal with typescript 5

Tags: reactjs, npm, wallet-connect, web3modal, wagmi

I wanted to play around with web3modal (walletconnect) in typescript.

I followed [the official guide](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/web/web3modal/react/wagmi/installation), but was unable to finish my setup due to dependency problems

to reproduce simply run the following:

1. `npx create-react-app web3modal --template typescript`
2. `cd web3modal`
3. `npm install @web3modal/ethereum @web3modal/react wagmi viem`
   [initial problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XKXS.png)

so I tried to solve it:

4. `npm i typescript@^5` (which results in warning shown below)
   [warnings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhH5L.png)
5. `npm install @web3modal/ethereum @web3modal/react wagmi viem`
   which results in more errors now, screenshot truncated
   [more errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOk86.png)

I tried searching for a version of web3modal that uses typescript ^4, but after going down to 2.3.0 - it still sits at 5.0.4.

so my question is:
is there any react/typescript example that uses up to date versions of web3modal? and if not - what are the versions of web3modal/wagmi/viem that I can downgrade to to still use typescript 4.9.5?

edit: I'm aware that [this exists](https://github.com/WalletConnect/web3modal-examples/tree/main/web3modal-wagmi-react), but it's missing the typescript part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to wagmi dep https://wagmi.sh/react/typescript

you'll need to run npm i --legacy-peer-deps

and for compile issues:

Try adding `"skipLibCheck": true` in the tsconfig.json file.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I do have `skipLibCheck` set to `true`, but this happens (I believe at least) before we get to tsconfig. I'm not quite sure how this is all handled, but errors happen during `npm i`, I didn't get to `npm run build` where I think tsconfig would be used

Comment: oh, you'll need to run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: that did help indeed, thanks. just please add this to your main response, so others can see it as well :)  I'll accept it as is tho